# Continuous function and the openess of points

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that I have a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f(a) = f(b) $ where $a$ and $b$ are points of $X$. Is it the case that we have that either both $a$ and $b$ are open or neither $a$ nor $b$ are open?

Thanks

Comment: Hopefully $a$ is a point of $X$ and $b$ is a point of $y$...

Comment: @Arthur: That would make the question nonsense, so let's not hope that.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: Note that you don't say "$a$ is open", but rather "(the set) $\{a\}$ is open".

Answer (score 5):

Notice that a constant function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous. And  for any two points $x,y \in X$ that $f(x)=f(y)$. This hold for any topology on $X$ so we have that $\{x\}$ can be open, closed or neither and similarly for $\{y\}$ with no dependence between the two.